# Trouble with Android JSONObject from Grails webservice

Tags: android, json, grails

Okay I am quering data from a Grails webservice that returns JSON.  The JSON when viewed with the JSONViewer app parses fine.  When I take that same string and use JSONObject(string) in my Android app I get "value of String cannot be converted to JSONObject."

Here's my JSON string

```
[[{"class":"mygrails.TopTen","id":491,"ttAmount":14200000,"ttMlId":402,"ttRank":1,"ttWeekId":1108},{"class":"mygrails.MovieList","id":402,"mlApproved":1,"mlApprovedId":5,"mlMovieId":"GNOMEOAN","mlReleaseDate":"2011-03-08T07:41:45Z","mlTitle":"Gnomeo and Juliet","mlWeekId":1106}]]
```

Now the JSON is comes from the standard JSON conversion of a SQL data using render from the groovy file through the import grails.converters.JSON.

```
... //(call to render JSON in the groovy file)
def a
a = Table.findAll("from someTable as st where st.id=" params.id)
render a as JSON
...
```

So I am not sure what I doing wrong and why the JSON looks a little off to me. (still new to JSON)

Comment: the JSON parses just fine on the online parser: http://json.parser.online.fr/. Do you have more information / code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In json if you see "[]" means its a json array and if you see "{}" it is an json object. Both of then can have the other nested inside then.

In your case the string the starts with json array.

So try something like the following

```
String str = "[[{"class":"mygrails.TopTen","id":491,"ttAmount":14200000,"ttMlId":402,"ttRank":1,"ttWeekId":1108},{"class":"mygrails.MovieList","id":402,"mlApproved":1,"mlApprovedId":5,"mlMovieId":"GNOMEOAN","mlReleaseDate":"2011-03-08T07:41:45Z","mlTitle":"Gnomeo and Juliet","mlWeekId":1106}]]";

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);

jsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);

JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

String class = jsonObject.getString("class"); // class will value "mygrails.TopTen"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  As I am new to JSON, didn't realize that it could return Array too instead. Is there a way to force the groovy code to render object instead of array?

Comment: I am not familiar with groovy but I guess would be possible. I think at the moment you are converting the entire result set of the sql select to json and I guess the result set is an array. In order to return a json object you should only convert the item in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create an JSONArray from the String instead of JSONObject. I didn't test this but that should do the trick: you have two nested arrays that contain then actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your JSON online with http://jsonformat.com/

http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html

JSON Viewer
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Paste your text in there and you can see what you should parse: